# Why does the keystore contain the signature of the signed app

Tags: android, certificate, keystore, sha1, signing

When i execute this command on my apk:

```
keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA
```

If i understand correctly, i can see the SHA1 fingerprint hash (encrypted by the private key):

```
SHA1: 16:59:E7:E3:0C:AA:7A:0D:F2:0D:05:20:12:A8:85:0B:32:C5:4F:68
```

But when i do this:

```
keytool -list -keystore my-signing-key.keystore
```

the same SHA1 key will be shown:

```
android_key, Jan 23, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 16:59:E7:E3:0C:AA:7A:0D:F2:0D:05:20:12:A8:85:0B:32:C5:4F:68
```

I want to know why this encrypted hash is in my keystore. I thought that it only stores the private key, i read this "A keystore is a binary file that contains one or more private keys" here: (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

Can someone enlighten me on this please?

Comment: A quick google search brought up these sites: https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO4264&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1254035702036 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint

Comment: My question is: why does the keystore contain the fingerprint instead of the private key. Not: "What is a fingerprint?"